# Javascript : Escaping single quote in function parameter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, escaping, single-quotes

In a span tag, I have a function where parameter value can be a string with single quote.

But even if I escape single quote by antislash, browser console displays error.

Here my code :

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function check(val)
{
    console.log(val);
}

</script>   

<span contenteditable onkeydown='check("foo\'foo");'>abc</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Why the escaping doesn't work ?

Comment: I'd also like to know, but in the mean time you could use
`<span contenteditable onkeydown="check('foo\'foo');">abc</span>`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<span contenteditable onkeydown="alert('foo\'foo');">abc</span>
```

will do the trick.